# jQuery change form action based on selected value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

ive run into a quite tricky problem while using a method to set the form action when value changes. I have got the following code :

```
var actions = new Array();
actions[0] = "some-site.html";
actions[1] = "some-other-site.html";
actions[2] = "another-site.html";
etc....

$("select#feld-urlaubsart").change(function () {
if ($("select#fieldname").val() !== "") {
$("form#searchform").attr("action","http://www.mysite.com/" +  
actions[$("select#fieldname").val()]);
}
});
```

On the other side, my select looks like this :

```
<select id="fieldname" name="fieldname">
<option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
<optgroup label="Golfurlaub mit Greenfees">
<option value="1">Alle Greenfee-Angebote</option>
<option value="2">Top-Angebote</option>
<option value="3">Golfurlaub mit 4 Tage Greenfee</option>
</optgroup>
```

Actually it does work but i am not happy with it as i need to rely on the value="1" value="2" etc.

Now i need to use the actual description as value to be compatible with another script that i pass the value to for usage in PHP/JSON. I would need the data like this

```
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
etc
```

How can i change the action of the form based on the selected VALUE while not needing to use array keys like "1" "2" etc?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Add the numbers as data-attributes to the <option>, or create a huge switch statement to compare Value and select correct array num are 2 options that come to mind.

Comment: I would not do that in javascript but in php when the form is submitted, just take a different action depending on the select and redirect after processing to wherever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a json object:

```
actions = {"All":"some-site.html","Option1":"some-other-site.html"}
```

Then

```
actions["All"]
```

is

```
"some-site.html"
```

Comment: Sounds good, but how would i implement that correctly? Can you please give me some advice? ;)

Comment: Swap out your actions array for the object. Put the values for your select as attributes and your html pages as the corresponding values.